# netplan - expected scalar on ip-address

Tags: server, 18.04, netplan

Every time, when I entered my ip-address of my server, the message **"Scalar expected"** appears during applying my netplan config.

My server has a 
 - static ipv4 address: x.x.126.104 
 - gateway: x.x.126.1 
 - subnet 255.255.255.0 
 - OS: Ubuntu Server 18.04

Below my configuration

```
network: 
        ethernets: 
                eth0: 
                        dhcp4: false 
                        dhcp6: false 
                        addresses: [x.x.126.104/24] 
                        gateway4: [x.x.126.1] 
                        nameservers: 
                                search: [xxx.home] 
                                addresses: [x.x.126.1]
```

What is wrong with the prefix "/24" in my static ip-address?

Kind regards, 
Kevin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gateway4` wants a scalar and you gave it an array. Try `gateway4: x.x.126.1`, with real numbers instead of `x.x`, of course.

See the [Netplan reference](https://netplan.io/reference) documentation.